# Search multiple keywords in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to complete this task as efficient as possible.
Here is how I want it to work.Say user inputs

```
"My screen is broken"
```

The script finds the two keywords "screen" and "broken" and then prints an appropriate string. Being a noob I thought I might be able to use a dictionary like this

```
{"screen", "broken", "smashed":"use a repair kit"}
```

Then I would just search all the keys in the dictionary.
But upon further research it seems this is not possible.

So what would be the best way to do this? I thought maybe sql but I was wondering if there was a better way which would involve just python.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on zyxue's answer, you could make it check for certain values but not all of them. This will work with your above code, but you can nest multiple tuples together if you'd like to group other names.

```
sentence = "My screen is smashed"

solution_dict = {}
solution_dict[("screen", ("broken", "smashed"))] = "use a repair kit"

#If value is a tuple, run function on every value and return if there are any matches
#If not, check the word is part of the sentence
def check_match(sentence_words, keyword):
    if isinstance(keyword, tuple):
        return any([check_match(sentence_words, i) for i in keyword])
    return keyword in sentence_words

#Make sure each value in the main tuple has a match
sentence_words = [i.lower() for i in sentence.split()]
for k,v in solution_dict.iteritems():
    if all(check_match(sentence_words, i) for i in k):
        print v
```

So you'll get results like this:

```
>>> sentence = "My screen is smashed"
use a repair kit
>>> sentence = "My screen is smashed and broken"
use a repair kit
>>> sentence = "My screen is broken"
use a repair kit
>>> sentence = "My phone is broken"
(nothing)
```

To work with phone too, along with iphone and android, you could set it like this, having iphone and android in another tuple makes no difference but just groups it a little better.
 `solution_dict[(("screen", "phone", ("android", "iphone")), ("broken", "smashed"))] = "use a repair kit"`

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for "screen" and "broken", something like this can work.

```
sentence = "My screen is broken"
keys = ["screen", "broken"]

if all(i in sentence for i in keys):
    print "Use a repair kit"
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary keys need to be immutable, you could use a tuple, e.g.

```
# {("screen", "broken"): "use a repair kit"}

# input is a keyword in Python, so use input_ instead
input_ = input_.split()
if 'screen' in input_ and 'broken' in input_:
    return "use a repair kit"
```

Comment: Would be great if you would add a snippet for the look-up algorithm since this seems to be a second point of the question.

Comment: Need better problem definition, so it's just about looking for 'screen' and 'broken'?

Comment: As far as I understood looking for screen, broken and smashed. @Lil B: Please clarify.

Comment: I only want to look for "screen" and "broken"

Comment: I've updated the answer, but it looks overly simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
solutions = [{'keywords': ['screen', 'broken', 'smashed'], 'solution': 'use a repair kit'}]
s = 'My screen is broken'
words = set(s.lower().split(' '))
print '\n'.join([x.get('solution') for x in solutions if words & set(x.get('keywords', []))])
```